# AngularJS input field value not showing when using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The input fields values not showing in the input fields. I used both **ng-model** & **data-ng-model**. Without using **ng-model** the values are displaying.

**i.e 1:**

```
<input type="text" value="{{accountDetailsBody.phoneNumber}}" data-ng-model="vm.user.phoneno" name="phoneno" id="phoneno" class="form-control">
```

**i.e 2:**

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="vm.user.email" readonly ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/" placeholder="Email" ng-maxlength="30" required>
```

**Controller**

```
 (function () {
        'use strict';
        angular
                .module('app')
                .controller('accountController', accountController);
        accountController.$inject = ['ApiService', '$rootScope', 'UserService', '$scope', '$location'];
        function accountController(ApiService, $rootScope, UserService, $scope, $location) {
            $scope.accountDetailsBody = {};
            var vm = this;
            vm.userUpdate = userUpdate;

            initController();
            function initController() {
                loadCurrentUser();
            }

            function userUpdate() {
                console.log(vm.user);
            }

function loadCurrentUser() {
            $scope.data = {'email': $rootScope.globals.currentUser.username};
            UserService.GetByUsername($scope.data).then(function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $scope.accountDetailsBody = response.user[0];
                } else {
                    $location.path('/');
                }
                //vm.user = user;
            });
        }
        }

    })();
```

Comment: show your controller

Comment: this is my controller :D

Comment: what kind of codes this!!!! are you sure this controller has related to that inputs !?

Comment: ng-model not your problem, i think you should explain what you want to do first

Comment: @Maher yah i'm sure.

Comment: i want to display the values inside the input field

<input type="text" value="{{accountDetailsBody.phoneNumber}}" data-ng-model="vm.user.phoneno" name="phoneno" id="phoneno" class="form-control">

{{accountDetailsBody.phoneNumber}} - this value not displaying when i using ng-model

Comment: ok, so what is "loadCurrentUser()" in your controler & where is your vm.user object

Comment: sorry i forgot to implement the loadCurrentUser() now you can get idea from above controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to set value here.
you can bind value directly to input text box with ng-model

try with this

**Controller**

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        angular
                .module('app')
                .controller('accountController', accountController);
        accountController.$inject = ['ApiService', '$rootScope', 'UserService', '$scope', '$location'];
        function accountController(ApiService, $rootScope, UserService, $scope, $location) {

            var vm = this;
            vm.accountDetailsBody = {};
            vm.userUpdate = userUpdate;

            initController();
            function initController() {
                loadCurrentUser();
            }

            function userUpdate() {
                console.log(vm.user);
            }

function loadCurrentUser() {
            $scope.data = {'email': $rootScope.globals.currentUser.username};
            UserService.GetByUsername($scope.data).then(function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    vm.accountDetailsBody = response.user[0];
                } else {
                    $location.path('/');
                }
                //vm.user = user;
            });
        }
        }

    })();
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.accountDetailsBody.phoneNumber" name="phoneno" id="phoneno" class="form-control">
```

Comment: if its working then you can check right and upvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `value="accountDetailsBody.phoneNumber"` instead of `value="{{accountDetailsBody.phoneNumber}}"`.

As `{{binding}}` is one way binding.. and `ng-mode="binding"` is two way binding.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use value attribute on html tag , you can assign ng-model value equels to your value in controller .

```
<input type="text"  data-ng-model="vm.user.phoneno" name="phoneno" id="phoneno" class="form-control">
```

in controller :

```
this.user.phoneno=accountDetailsBody.phoneNumber
```

Comment: could you please tel how to defined user in controller?

Comment: initilize with this.user={}